# Converting distance SQL function to Cake friendly query using ORM

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to convert below SQL string into Cake find query.
Is there an easy way of doing this?

```
SELECT longitude, latitude, firstname, surname, profile_pic, facebook_id, distance 
                FROM 
              (SELECT longitude, latitude, firstname, surname, profile_pic, facebook_id, 6371 * ACos( Cos( RADIANS( users.latitude ) ) * Cos( RADIANS( $latitude ) ) * Cos( RADIANS( $longitude ) - RADIANS( users.longitude ) ) + Sin( RADIANS( users.latitude ) ) * Sin( RADIANS( $latitude ) ) ) AS distance
               FROM users
              ) as users
              WHERE distance <=2 AND facebook_id != $facebook
              ORDER BY distance
              LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Is there a reason why it has to be in a `find()` query? You can just leave it as is and use `query()` instead.

Comment: You have to do it using subquery, or change your query to have the HAVING cluase (for the distance) and then you can do it even easier just as a normal find....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a code snippet doing something similar:

```
$GeoCache->virtualFields = array(
    'distance' => "SQRT(POW(UserGeolocationCache.latitude - {$latitude},2) + POW(UserGeolocationCache.longitude - {$longitude},2))"
);
$users = $GeoCache->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('distance <' => '0.05'),
    'order' => array('distance asc'),
    'contain' => array('User'),
));
```

TL;DR just stuff your distance calculation in a virtual field and search on it.